# How we can trigger test cycle RUN button automatically at particular time for overnight testing using silk central?

Tags: automation

I have one requirement regarding silk central how I can trigger RUN button in silk central automatically?
Scenario:
Suppose I want to start test cycle at 2PM night without human interaction so how  it can be done using silk central

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silk Central has the ability to schedule runs, through the Execution Plans.

You will find the tab Schedule under the **Execution Planning -> Details View**, and this allows you to create a custom schedule or define a global schedule for your execution plans.

Setting up global schedules, are possible through **Execution Planning -> Schedules**, this is where you can define your global daily schedule as described above.